# get menue items from Database sorted in list elements of 5 each

Tags: database, html-lists

I wonder if I could get the values and links of my top menue from database, just like hand writing it...
at the moment i write something like:

```
           <div class="ruby-row">
                <div class="ruby-col-2">
                  <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Menu Item #1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Menu Item #2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Menu Item #3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Menu Item #4</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Menu Item #5</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="ruby-col-2">
                 <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Menu Item #1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Menu Item #2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Menu Item #3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Menu Item #4</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Menu Item #5</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="ruby-col-2">
                 <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Menu Item #1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Menu Item #2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Menu Item #3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Menu Item #4</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Menu Item #5</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
```

............
So  I would need to get the data kind of sorted in groups of 5.
I know how to get all items in tables or divs but i never 
thought how to put data in ul and li's sorted by groups of for example 5.

Any Idea if that would be possible and if yes how
OR if that is the wrong way anyway...

Comment: you should look for `each_slice` enumerator. `[1,2,3,4,5,6].each_slice(3)` return `[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]`.

Comment: Type irb and type that `[1,2,3,4,5,6].each_slice(3){|t| p t}`

Comment: ... the data is in a mysql database.
at the moment the data output works like that: `
$query_Recordset8 = "SELECT * FROM table3 WHERE table3.Partner=1 ORDER BY RAND()";
$Recordset8 = mysql_query($query_Recordset8, $link) or die(mysql_error());
$row_Recordset8 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset8);
$totalRows_Recordset8 = mysql_num_rows($Recordset8);
`
`
<?php do { ?>
<?php echo $row_Recordset8['adress']; ?>
 <?php } while ($row_Recordset8 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset8)); ?>`

Comment: Can you post your db schema pls?

Comment: db=accomodation   |   table1:  hotels   | table2:  appartements    |  table3: b&b    |     content of a table:       id - accommodation_name- stars - address - email - homepage - rooms - service - photos......................

--> so I can call every accommodation type by a table or inquire for different accommodation typs   --      - every single accommodation can be assigned / printed  by id (unique) and get data specific for each search ....
>>> did you mean that by a db schema?